# sending a full react native project including all the files and ready to build

Tags: react-native, share

How do I send a react native project? (Maybe over Email)
What i know is that i can send the package.json and the source files and they can npm install these dependencies.. but there are many manually linked components and what about the android and ios folders?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Whom do you need to send it to?

Comment: why not github? or bitbucket if it has to be private?

Comment: i wanna send it to a client that wants to compile it himself.. i can use bitbucket but still i wanna know if there's a way to share the files directly with reducing the size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create an archive and send where you want, to reduce size you can exclude `node_modules` directory, which can be loaded with `npm install` command. Also, you can exclude following directories

`ios/build
ios/DerivedData
android/.gradle
android/app/build
android/app/release`

Comment: thanks for your answer.. are you sure that only the node modules can be excluded or more folders?

Comment: How is it that large? Are you sure the node modules are excluded? Do you have a ton of images/media assets/build assets? There's no way your source should be that large

Comment: @MahmoudDafer I've updated my answer, please have a look.

Comment: @Kai no there are only 2 images.. it's the react-native-firebase-starter-kit with few added components and fbsdk